# How to debug Play 2 Application built with Gradle

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, gradle, playframework

There seems to be extensive documentation for [debugging Play](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/IDE) applications [with IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-play2-app.html), but they all assume that Play is built with SBT.

Debugging with Gradle should be as easy as:

- Set some breakpoints
- Run `GRADLE_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=9999" gradlew --no-daemon :runPlayBinary`
- Run an IntelliJ Remote Configuration that looks like this:

[image: IntelliJ Remote Configuration]

- Hit http://localhost:9000 and do something interesting to cause a breakpoint to be hit

The problem I'm having is: *the breakpoint is never hit*, processing continues as normal. **Technologies: Play 2.3.X, IDEA 14.1, Gradle 2.8, Scala 2.10**

I must be missing something, what is it?

Comment: For curiosity could I ask why you are using gradle rather than sbt?

Comment: SBT doesn't "play" very well with our other Gradle projects because dependency management and other facets of builds are sometimes in conflict. Furthermore, our testing has shown Gradle to be much faster and more deterministic. My answer is actually much longer than this so it doesn't really fit as a comment.

Comment: Did you managed to solve it? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't solved this, yet.

Comment: @antonzy This has been answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting the debug argument in the wrong place. Setting it in the `GRADLE_OPTS` defines a system property to use when you're running Gradle. Because Gradle starts a new JVM process to execute the Play Framework application, you must carry these properties to the JVM runnning the application.

You can use the `PlayRun` task to add the JVM arguments. Something like this:

```
tasks.withType(PlayRun) {
    forkOptions.jvmArgs = ['-Xdebug', 
                          '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999']
}
```

But notice that this setting will set the debug mode every time you execute the application. Maybe you should add some argument to validate if you want the debug mode.

After that, you can normally set the remote debug in your IDE.

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Awesome-sauce, this works! Note for those reading this answer you must attach the debugger process as described in the question after running ./gradlew runPlayBinary

Comment: For Java version greater than 1.4, the arguments should be `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999`

Answer (score 1):

Building on joao's answer, you can create a new task and use your remote configuration to connect to it:

```
task debugPlayBinary {
    doLast {
        def runPlayTask = tasks.findByName('runPlayBinary')
        runPlayTask.forkOptions.jvmArgs = ['-Xdebug', '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005']
        runPlayTask.run()
    }
}
```

This allows `runPlayBinary` to remain untouched.

Comment: note: 'tasks.findByName('runPlay')' is the right syntax now

Answer (score 1):

Play 2.7, Java 8, Gradle combo required the following:
run it with: `gradle runPlay -Ddebug=true`

````
play {
    injectedRoutesGenerator = true
    platform {
        playVersion = playV
        scalaVersion = scalaV
        javaVersion = javaV
    }
    if (System.getProperty("debug")) {
        def runPlayTask = tasks.findByName('runPlay')
        runPlayTask.forkOptions.jvmArgs = ['-Xdebug', '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005']
    }
}```
````

Comment: Note: "suspend=y," means that it will wait for the debug port to be connected before moving on.